# Why Does Razor CSHTML Code Display as Plain Text?

Tags: razor, iis-7.5

My organization is contemplating a move to .NET Razor.  I am trying to learn it; and to do so I would like to write test scripts; however, after I copied some code into a CSHTML file and navigated to the URL, the Razor code is displayed on the page.

The code below is what I am testing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    Hello, @Request["name"]
</body>
</html>
```

When viewed in the browser (ex: http://mysite/test.cshtml?name=Bob) we see:

*Hello, @Request["name"]* instead of *Hello, Rob*

My teammates verified:

- .NET 4.5 is installed
- .NET MVC 3.0 is installed
- The application pool is running in Integrated mode
- We ran `aspnet_regiis.exe -iru`
- The *.cshtml extension is mapped to a handler

Our server is IIS 7.5 running on Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: I have seen the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101635/razor-cshtml-displays-plain-text-windows-server-2008-and-iis7 and did not glean an answer from it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.

Check whether you are using any key in the controller which is not defined or is commented in the Web.config.

My issue is resolved. I was using a key with the help of ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in my controller. But it was not present in the Web.config. As soon as I added it in my Web.config it all started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a Razor Web Pages site in visual studio by going to File » New » Web Site. You can get more information about ASP.NET Web Pages from here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages.
It is the recommended starting point for people who are new to ASP.NET development

Comment: This does not answer the question; but, I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Did you activated the *.cshtml extension and linked it to the application pool?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the MIME type is mapped to a handler.